# Foreign key is showing null while inserting into Child Table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, hibernate-mapping

I was trying to insert each parent table primary key Id into child table as a foreign key.First the parent table will update then the relevant child. But when I tried it always showing null.But If I only instert master data the primary key is generating properly. I was using JPA @OneToMany relationship in parent and @ManyToOne in child..

My First class is...(Which is transaction master class)

```
package com.org.pc.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.*;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;


/**
 * The persistent class for the physical_allocation_master database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="physical_allocation_master", schema="spc_cg")
@NamedQuery(name="PhysicalAllocationMaster.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM PhysicalAllocationMaster p")
public class PhysicalAllocationMaster implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="BudgetUpload_GENERATOR",sequenceName="spc_cg.seq_budget_id",allocationSize=1,initialValue=1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="BudgetUpload_GENERATOR",strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name="physical_allocation_m_id")
    private Integer physicalAllocationMId;

    @Column(name="allocation_entry_by")
    private String allocationEntryBy;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="date_of_entry")
    private Date dateOfEntry;

    @Column(name="is_approved")
    private Integer isApproved;

    @Column(name="location_id")
    private Integer locationId;

    @Column(name="location_type_id")
    private Integer locationTypeId;

    @Column(name="scheme_id")
    private Integer schemeId;

    @Column(name="year_id")
    private Integer yearId;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to PhysicalAllocationDetail
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="physicalAllocationMaster", cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<PhysicalAllocationDetail> physicalAllocationDetails;

    public PhysicalAllocationMaster() {
    }

    public Integer getPhysicalAllocationMId() {
        return this.physicalAllocationMId;
    }

    public void setPhysicalAllocationMId(Integer physicalAllocationMId) {
        this.physicalAllocationMId = physicalAllocationMId;
    }

    public String getAllocationEntryBy() {
        return this.allocationEntryBy;
    }

    public void setAllocationEntryBy(String allocationEntryBy) {
        this.allocationEntryBy = allocationEntryBy;
    }

    public Date getDateOfEntry() {
        return this.dateOfEntry;
    }

    public void setDateOfEntry(Date dateOfEntry) {
        this.dateOfEntry = dateOfEntry;
    }

    public Integer getIsApproved() {
        return this.isApproved;
    }

    public void setIsApproved(Integer isApproved) {
        this.isApproved = isApproved;
    }

    public Integer getLocationId() {
        return this.locationId;
    }

    public void setLocationId(Integer locationId) {
        this.locationId = locationId;
    }

    public Integer getLocationTypeId() {
        return this.locationTypeId;
    }

    public void setLocationTypeId(Integer locationTypeId) {
        this.locationTypeId = locationTypeId;
    }

    public Integer getSchemeId() {
        return this.schemeId;
    }

    public void setSchemeId(Integer schemeId) {
        this.schemeId = schemeId;
    }

    public Integer getYearId() {
        return this.yearId;
    }

    public void setYearId(Integer yearId) {
        this.yearId = yearId;
    }

    public List<PhysicalAllocationDetail> getPhysicalAllocationDetails() {
        return this.physicalAllocationDetails;
    }

    public void setPhysicalAllocationDetails(List<PhysicalAllocationDetail> physicalAllocationDetails) {
        this.physicalAllocationDetails = physicalAllocationDetails;
    }

    public PhysicalAllocationDetail addPhysicalAllocationDetail(PhysicalAllocationDetail physicalAllocationDetail) {
        getPhysicalAllocationDetails().add(physicalAllocationDetail);
        physicalAllocationDetail.setPhysicalAllocationMaster(this);

        return physicalAllocationDetail;
    }

    public PhysicalAllocationDetail removePhysicalAllocationDetail(PhysicalAllocationDetail physicalAllocationDetail) {
        getPhysicalAllocationDetails().remove(physicalAllocationDetail);
        physicalAllocationDetail.setPhysicalAllocationMaster(null);

        return physicalAllocationDetail;
    }
```

My Second class is(Child Class)....

```
package com.org.pc.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.*;


/**
 * The persistent class for the physical_allocation_detail database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="physical_allocation_detail", schema="spc_cg")
@NamedQuery(name="PhysicalAllocationDetail.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM PhysicalAllocationDetail p")
public class PhysicalAllocationDetail implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="BudgetUpload_GENERATOR",sequenceName="spc_cg.seq_budget_id",allocationSize=1,initialValue=1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="BudgetUpload_GENERATOR",strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name="physical_allocation_d_id")
    private Integer physicalAllocationDId;

    private double general;

    @Column(name="physical_target")
    private double physicalTarget;

    private double sc;

    @Column(name="scheme_component_id")
    private Integer schemeComponentId;

    private double st;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to PhysicalAllocationMaster
    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="physical_allocation_m_id", insertable = true, updatable = true, nullable=false)
    private PhysicalAllocationMaster physicalAllocationMaster;

    public PhysicalAllocationDetail() {
    }

    public Integer getPhysicalAllocationDId() {
        return this.physicalAllocationDId;
    }

    public void setPhysicalAllocationDId(Integer physicalAllocationDId) {
        this.physicalAllocationDId = physicalAllocationDId;
    }

    public double getGeneral() {
        return this.general;
    }

    public void setGeneral(double general) {
        this.general = general;
    }

    public double getPhysicalTarget() {
        return this.physicalTarget;
    }

    public void setPhysicalTarget(double physicalTarget) {
        this.physicalTarget = physicalTarget;
    }

    public double getSc() {
        return this.sc;
    }

    public void setSc(double sc) {
        this.sc = sc;
    }

    public Integer getSchemeComponentId() {
        return this.schemeComponentId;
    }

    public void setSchemeComponentId(Integer schemeComponentId) {
        this.schemeComponentId = schemeComponentId;
    }

    public double getSt() {
        return this.st;
    }

    public void setSt(double st) {
        this.st = st;
    }

    public PhysicalAllocationMaster getPhysicalAllocationMaster() {
        return this.physicalAllocationMaster;
    }

    public void setPhysicalAllocationMaster(PhysicalAllocationMaster physicalAllocationMaster) {
        this.physicalAllocationMaster = physicalAllocationMaster;
    }
```

And the controller part for transaction is.....

```
PhysicalAllocationMaster physicalAllocationMaster=new PhysicalAllocationMaster();
PhysicalAllocationDetail physicalAllocationDetail= new PhysicalAllocationDetail();
List<LocationMaster> locationMasterList=locationMasterService.findByProperty("locationId", Integer.parseInt(serial[i]));
Integer locationMasterListSize = locationMasterList.size();
if(locationMasterListSize!=0){
    physicalAllocationMaster.setLocationId(locationMasterList.get(0).getLocationId()); 
    physicalAllocationMaster.setLocationTypeId(locationMasterList.get(0).getLocationTypeId());
}
else{
    logger.info("Location is not present for Id "+serial[i]);
}
physicalAllocationMaster.setSchemeId(schemeId);
physicalAllocationMaster.setYearId(yearId);
physicalAllocationMaster.setDateOfEntry(sqlDate);
physicalAllocationMaster.setAllocationEntryBy(allocEntryBy);
physicalAllocationMaster.setIsApproved(1);
physicalAllocationDetail.setSchemeComponentId(schemeComponenet);
if(general.length !=0 && general[i] != null && general[i].toString().trim().length() > 0){      physicalAllocationDetail.setGeneral(Double.parseDouble(general[i]));
}else{
    physicalAllocationDetail.setGeneral(0);
}
if(sc.length!=0 && sc[i] != null && sc[i].toString().trim().length() > 0){
    physicalAllocationDetail.setSc(Double.parseDouble(sc[i]));
}else{
    physicalAllocationDetail.setSc(0);
}
if(st.length!=0 && st[i] != null && st[i].toString().trim().length() > 0){
    physicalAllocationDetail.setSt(Double.parseDouble(st[i]));
}else{
    physicalAllocationDetail.setSt(0);
}
if(total.length!=0 && total[i] != null && total[i].toString().trim().length() > 0){
    physicalAllocationDetail.setPhysicalTarget(Double.parseDouble(total[i]));
}else{
    physicalAllocationDetail.setPhysicalTarget(0);
}
logger.info("Physical Allocation Master Primary Key: "+physicalAllocationMaster.getPhysicalAllocationMId());
physicalAllocationDetailSet.add(physicalAllocationDetail);                  physicalAllocationMaster.addPhysicalAllocationDetail(physicalAllocationDetail);
physicalAllocationMaster.setPhysicalAllocationDetails(physicalAllocationDetailSet);
physicalAllocationMasterService.persist(physicalAllocationMaster);
```

Please help on this. I am not well versed on JPA or Hibernate.

Comment: you most setMaster in your detail before you persist your master,

Comment: Sorry but the last two commeented line was not working... Thats why I commented it...How can I supposed to set master in detail

Comment: I cannot see any commented line in your code. but in your detail you have a setter method for master. set your master with this. `physicalAllocationDetail.setPhysicalAllocationMaster(physicalAllocationMaster)`. set master in detail before persist master.

Comment: Thanks.. I tried it and now its working. Thanks for help...